# Hero update lead to deletion of widgets

Tags: 2.1-eclair, htc-sense, htc-hero

I have an HTC Hero (Europe) with Sense with used to run 2.1. A few days ago it said it wanted to update.
I allowed it and now the SMS widget is missing. The widget on the startscreen that also has weather information is missing as well.

How do I get those back?

Answer (score 1):

Just got the same issue today. Reboot the phone once more, and you should be able to re-add the widgets back manually. Unfortunately there seems to be no other way to do this. Some widgets (bookmarks for example) were not even available for adding without additional phone reboot.